# Httpwebreqest post parameter

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

```
HttpWebRequest erequestScore = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
postData = "post[title]=" + textbox_title.Text +"&post[content]=" + textbox_content.Text + "&fid=47&Subit=Submit";
data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
erequestScore.Method = "Post";
erequestScore.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
erequestScore.ContentLength = data.Length;
 erequestScore.KeepAlive = true;
```

But the problem is that my textbox_title.Text contents html code which have & symbol and the post data will stop before the &. How to solve? System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode or System.Net.WebUtility? and how to apply ?

Comment: I have solved bymyself, parameter surrounded with System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode is good

Answer (score 0):

you can post it with the WebClient object, which can post a NameValueCollection:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
   var data = new NameValueCollection();
   data["fid"] = "47";
   data["someOtherName"] = "value";
   var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
}
```